# Scatter Plot 2D Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot

I've (single) `3430X6906` matrix having only zeros and ones and I want to scatter plot it. Suppose I've *1 on column 30 and row 40*, the plot should have `dot` on point (30,40).

Can you please help me to plot it.

Comment: [`spy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spy.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the row and column using [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and then plot these using [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).

```
%// Create artificial data
data = rand(3430, 6906) > 0.99999;

%// Find the location of the ones
[row, col] = find(data);

%// Plot these locations
plot(col, row, 'o')
```

[image]